# DatePicker not returning selected date iOS

Tags: ios, date, datepicker, selected, picker

I am trying to get the selected date from a DatePicker and all I get is the current system date. Any ideas why?

I am doing it through the simulator as I do not have a device. Here is the code I use to get the date.

```
 [self scheduleLocalNotification:timerPicker.date];
```

I have also used this to see if it works:

```
 NSDate *d = [timerPicker date];

 [self scheduleLocalNotification:d];
```

Comment: Code like this works for me. Are you properly instantiating the `UIDatePicker` and using the `datePickerMode` you want?

Comment: Here is what I hace in the header file "IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timerPicker" and then I don't do anything else in the code but in the xib interface I have it with these settings. The mode is set to "Date and Time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several reboots of XCode and no code changes it magically started working.